# signtool.exe not found?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Alright, so I'm trying to publish something in VS2010, and it's saying signtool not found. I tried copying it and pasting it in the VS2010 SDK 3.5 directory, but it's still not working. I tired reinstalling VS2010 but it's still not working.

How do I get past this stupid error?

Comment: what is the error you're seeing (including the path that VS2010 is looking for)?  If you're using VS2010, could it be that the compiler is looking for the tool in the .NET 4 directory?

Comment: Error 8 An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found. --- Also I don't have a .net 4.0 directory only a 3.5

Comment: It should be found at: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin`

Comment: Yeah, I found it, now how do I make VS2010 see it?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Please Click Once application --> Properties --> Signing -> Unchecked the Sign the ClickOnce manifests.

Problem will be solved.